# This is an IP range?

Tags: networking, ip, firewall

guys, need the help, I am asking the vendor for a ip range to add to our whitelist, they responded 
'
201.21.206.128 255.255.255.192
'

Is this a range at all? if so what ip addresses included? sorry my network skills really low. thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: The second is a subnet mask, http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a valid IP range. It provides your 62 usable hosts.

```
Subnet 201.21.206.128 /26
Network ID 201.21.206.128
First usable host 201.21.206.129
Last usable host 201.21.206.190
Broadcast ID 201.21.206.191
```

If you want more detailed info, post a comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

HostMin:   201.21.206.129        11001001.00010101.11001110.10 000001

HostMax:   201.21.206.190        11001001.00010101.11001110.10 111110

Hosts/Net: 62

Comment: you should clarify to the OP why you are writing them in binary format, and why is that useful regarding netmasks.